# Why doesn't std::make_shared fail to compile for type with deleted operator new?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm trying to write a heap prohibited type, i.e. a type that's not constructible on heap allocated memory. By deleting the operator new and placement new I thought I'd achieve this. But creating a shared pointer using `std::make_shared` still compiles.

Why doesn't `std::make_shared<A>()` fail to compile when the new operators are deleted?

```
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t) = delete;
    void* operator new(size_t, void*) = delete;
    void* operator new [] (size_t) = delete;
};

// Regular new fails
A* a1 = new A();

// Placement new fails
void* pv = std::malloc(sizeof(A));
A* a2 = new (pv) A();

// make_shared works
std::shared_ptr<A> a3 = std::make_shared<A>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::make_shared` is specified in terms of `::​new (pv) T(std​::​forward<Args>(args)...)`.

> **[util.smartptr.shared.create]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/util.smartptr.shared.create#2) *Effects*: Allocates memory suitable for an object of type T
>   and constructs an object in that memory via the placement
>   new-expression​ `::​new (pv) T(std​::​forward<Args>(args)...)`. The
>   template allocate_­shared uses a copy of a to allocate memory. If an
>   exception is thrown, the functions have no effect.

The memory allocated is usually for a control block, and not directly a `new T`. The object is then constructed via placement new, but the new expression is fully qualified to use the global placement `operator new`, instead of any class specific ones.

> **[expr.new]**
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#9) If the new-expression begins with a unary `​::` ​operator, the
>   allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.
>   Otherwise, if the allocated type is a class type T or array thereof,
>   the allocation function's name is looked up in the scope of T. If this
>   lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is not a class
>   type, the allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.

Those two uses would bypass your custom deleted operators entirely.